# Move list of users from one OU to a different OU and disable them at the same time - Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, get-aduser

I currently have a script that is able to disable a list of usernames using a text file which has a list of username specified:

```
$users = Get-Content C:\disableusers.txt

foreach ($user in $users) {
    Disable-ADAccount -Identity $user
    Write-Host "user $($user) has been disabled"
}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to incorporate moving using from one OU to another during the execution of this script?

e.g. moving from "Users" OU to "Disabled Users" OU.

I have created another script which does move a list of usernames to "Disabled Users" OU:

```
$users=Get-Content C:\disableusers.txt

$OU = "distinguishedName of my Disable Users OU"

foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-ADUser $user | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $OU 
}
```

Any help on this is much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your snippets look good to me, if you are interested in combining them into one you could use `-PassThru` from [`Disable-ADAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/disable-adaccount?view=windowsserver2022-ps) to pass the disabled object through the pipeline to [`Move-ADObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/move-adobject?view=windowsserver2022-ps):

```
$OU = "distinguishedName of my Disable Users OU"

Get-Content C:\disableusers.txt | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        Disable-ADAccount $_ -PassThru |
            Move-ADObject -TargetPath $ou

        Write-Host "user $($user) has been disabled and moved"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error $_
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was after something being combined into one piece of code. I know I forgot to ask this in the question.

Comment: @S.Mahmood glad this helped :)